# My debezium connector is not creating a new kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, debezium

I am using a debezium connector docker container + MySQL docker container + Kafka broker docker container (and pretty new to the concept :) ).

I am using these configurations for my connector:

```
{
    "name": "data_state_change_connector",
    "config": {
        "name": "data_state_change_connector",
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "subscription_contracts_kafka:9093",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "database.hostname": "subscription_contracts_db",
        "database.port": "3306",
        "database.user": "XXX",
        "database.password": "XXX",
        "database.server.id": "194154",
        "database.server.name": "subscription_contracts_db",
        "database.whitelist": "subscription-contracts",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "history.data_state_change",
        "database.allowPublicKeyRetrieval":"true",
        "table.whitelist": "subscription-contracts.subscription_contract",
        "message.key.columns": "subscription-contracts.subscription_contract:id",
        "include.schema.changes": "false",
        "transforms": "filter, unwrap",
        "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
        "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "true",
        "transforms.filter.type": "io.debezium.transforms.Filter",
        "transforms.filter.language": "jsr223.groovy",
        "transforms.filter.condition": "value.source.table == 'subscription_contract' && value.hasProperty('op') == true && (value.op == 'd' || value.op == 'c' || (value.op == 'u' && value.after.status != value.before.status))"
    }
}
```

I can see that the history topic that configured here `"database.history.kafka.topic": "history.data_state_change"` is created, but the regular topic is not being created, though I do see the changes in the container DB.

`http://localhost:8070/connectors/data_state_change_connector/status` shows that the connector and task are running.

Do you have an idea of what can be wrong with what I am doing?

Comment: Based on your previous question, after adding `value.hasProperty('op')`, this is false, making the entire filter false, and therefore there would be no data to send to (or create) a topic

Comment: First, your help with all my questions is much appreciated :)!
But I think the issue with my last question was that a migration query of schema change hasn't been able to be processed since it has no op field. Here I am talking about regular insert/update transactions that are not fetched by the connector.